# How to conditionally retrieve current user's doc fields in Firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I need to conditionally retrieve fields of current user's doc. Here is my Firestore db structure.

[image]

I need all map type objects (setup1, setup2, setup3...) and their fields, nothing else.

It is possible to conditionally get the needed fields of current user's doc as follows:

```
const userRef = collection(db, 'users');
const q = query(userRef, where('uid', '==', userID), where('config1', '!=', false));
const userDocs = await getDocs(q);
```

But I cannot do that as users have only read permission for their own doc:

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {
  match /users/{uid} {
    allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == uid;
  }
}
```

In addition, it is not possible to use "where" without "query":

```
const userRef = doc(db, 'users', userID); // can't use "where" here
// const userRef = doc(collection(db, 'users'), userID) // same here
const userDoc = await getDoc(userRef);
setUserData(userDoc.data());
```

Is it possible to somehow use "where" above or to filter fields from userDoc.data()?

Answer (score 1):

> I need all map type objects (setup1, setup2, setup3...) and their fields, nothing else.

That's not possible using the Firebase Client SDK. You can only fetch the whole document. [Firestore Node.JS SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/firestore) does support selecting required fields only but that is meant to be used on server side so you'll have to use [Cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/products/functions) or something similar.

> But I cannot do that as users have only read permission for their own doc:

`query(userRef, where('uid', '==', userID), where('config1', '!=', false));`

This query will not return any document because there's no `config1` field in the root of document.

> Is it possible to somehow use "where" above or to filter fields from userDoc.data()?

It might best to create a sub-collection `setups`. Then you should be able to run all your required queries.

```
users -> { userId } -> setups -> { setupId }
```

If each setup sub-document has the `configN` field the following query should return all users setups where the given config is true:

```
const userSetupRef = collection(db, `users/${userId}/setups`);

const q = query(userSetupRef, where('config1', '!=', false));
```